# Returning string array and use it on AutoCompleteTextview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, autocompletetextview

I'm developing an android application in which I retrieve some piece of data ( all the village village names) from SQLite database table. I returned this via String Array. Code is

```
public String[] getAllVillage()
 {
     String[] villagelist=new String[2000];
     int i=0;
     Cursor c=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MYDATABASE_TABLE2 ,null);
     if (c.moveToFirst())
     {
         do
         {
             villagelist[i]=c.getString(1);
             i++;
         }while(c.moveToNext());
     }
     c.close();
    return villagelist;
 }
```

and, In my android application I passed this array into AutoCompleteTextview as following:

```
private SQLiteAdapterv vadapter;
String[] village=new String[2000];
String newone[] = new String[2000];
village=vadapter.getAllVillage();
 for(int h=0;h<2000;h++)
 {
newone[h]=village[h];
 }
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,newone);
   final AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

   acTextView.setThreshold(0);
   acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
   acTextView.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

But the code has no effect which means, when I click the AutocompleteTextview, it won't show any villagenames. Is my method was correct? If not then help me to do this

Comment: did you set breakpoints and look through your code?  DO you know if your query is filling up `villagelist` ?

Comment: No I didn't check with breakpoints. Is my procedure is correct? I mean returning string array and implementing it

Comment: check [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-autocompletetextview.html) out.  They seem to be doing what you want. But I would start by placing breakpoints to make sure you are getting your data first.

Comment: I've checked. No problem in query. Both village and newone contains result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the problem in your code is

```
String[] village=new String[2000];// assigning large size
String newone[] = new String[2000];
```

The reason is assume that if only 1000 records are present in your database. these two string arrays contains 1000 result and null values upto the remaining. You can check by breakpoint. AutoComplete Textview doesn't support such format.

So you should make some changes in your code as

```
int count;
count=vadapter.getCount();
String[] village=new String[count];
village=vadapter.getAllVillage();
```

Then you can directly use village in setAdapter as

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,village);
```

Answer (score 1):

> ArrayAdapter adapter = new
>   ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,newone);

replace with this;

> ArrayAdapter adapter = new
>   ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,village);

Comment: did you break through it? are there any elements in either `village` or `newone`?  If they contain your villages, then you know the issue is in your code, if not, then you need to fix your query.  This is important to know

Comment: for(int h=0;h<vilage.legth;h++)
 {
newone[h]=village[h];
 }// then they become same nothing.. like just put your value 2000 into for loop

Comment: I've checked. No problem in query

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
acTextView.setThreshold(1);

acTextView.addTextChangedListener(this);

acTextView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, newone));
```