# AutoCompleteTextView Not Working Properly on adding data from Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, autocompletetextview

I have a **AutoCompleteTextView** which works fine when I define my string statically like this..

```
private String Names[] = {"Hassan", "Usman", "Kristen Stewart"};
```

then I do this..

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, Names);
    //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView

    catgNames.setThreshold(0);//will start working from 0 character
    catgNames.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
```

**But** when I try to load some data from **Sqlite**, the **drop down** suggestion doesn't work. I'm doing something like this..

```
  Categories = new String[100]
  int i =0;
  DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    List<entries> entries1 = db.getCategories();
    for (entries cn : entries1) {
        Log.i("", cn.getCategories());

        Names[i] = cn.getCategories();
        i++;
    }
```

and after this I define the adapter..

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, Names);
    //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView

    catgNames.setThreshold(0);//will start working from 0 character
    catgNames.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
```

This doesn't work. There is no error or warning in log-cat..

Comment: check is it the data avail in db or not.

Comment: I did.. It's there.. If that would have been the case then I would have solved it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem..

Here's the mistake I was doing..

```
Categories = new String[100]
```

this will create an array of size 100 which I wasn't using completely.

Now..

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
List<entries> entries1 = db.getCategories();
for (entries cn : entries1) {
    Log.i("", cn.getCategories());

    Names[i] = cn.getCategories();
    i++;
}
```

this code was only putting the values which were inside the Database and the rest of the values were still null in the Names array.

Due to this autocompletetextview was not working properly..

Here's how I solved it..

```
int i=0;
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    List<entries> entries1 = db.getCategories();
    for (entries cn : entries1) {
        i++;
    }
    Names = new String[i];
    int j=0;
    List<entries> entries3 = db.getCategories();
    for (entries cn : entries3) {
        Names[j] = cn.getCategories();
        j++;
    }
```

Found the solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14728357/3966666)

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
String[] Categories =[entries1.size];


int i =0;
  DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    List<entries> entries1 = db.getCategories();
    for (entries cn : entries1) {
        Log.i("", cn.getCategories());

    Categories[i] = cn.getCategories();
    i++;
}
```

Change your Threshold value :

```
catgNames.setThreshold(0);
```

like this.

```
catgNames.setThreshold(1);
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why would you pass Categories in your ArrayAdapter while you are adding your values into Names[]? It should be 'Names' instead of 'Categories' in your ArrayAdapter, as like

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, Names);
```

Or you can create a List, add all db column values and pass them in your ArrayAdapter. Hope it helps!

Comment: Or you can create a *List<String>, add all db column values and pass *it in your ArrayAdapter.

Comment: I have edited the code.. I made a mistake while asking question

Comment: I dont have any direct experience with local database, but I am assuming that you are retrieving all values in entries1 as a List. If it does work correctly, then you should get your code working by just replacing 'Names' with 'entries1'.